# Rx Observable - Chaining

Tags: .net, webclient, system.reactive

I have a function that downloads a csv file from the web. I need to extend it so that it makes 2 calls to 2 website one after the other. However i'm not sure how to do it...

Heres's the function:

```
// Define other methods and classes here
private void GetCSVData(string url1, string url2)
{
    WebClient webClient = null;
    try
    {
        webClient = new WebClient();

        var task = Observable.FromEventPattern
            <OpenReadCompletedEventHandler, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs>
        (
            ev => webClient.OpenReadCompleted += ev,
            ev => webClient.OpenReadCompleted -= ev
        );

        // needs to be redone
        task.Subscribe(t => ParseCSV1(t.EventArgs.Result));

        // call ParseCSV1()
        // then call ParseCSV2()

        // needs redone, 2 calls to 2 website
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url1));     
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(wex.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void ParseCSV1(Stream stream)
{
    // Parse steps...
}

private void ParseCSV2(Stream stream)
{
    // Parse steps...
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete. You have `url1` & `url2` coming in but you call `OpenReadAsync` with `url`. The intent of your code is unclear. Can you please improve this question?

Comment: Map the 2 urls to 2 observables, concat these 2 observable to get single observable and subscribe to it

Answer (score 1):

What you have *should* be ok.  If you make a second call to [`OpenReadAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openreadasync.aspx), then a second event will fire (one for each URL) and your subscription will process both.

You should simply be able to do the following:

```
// Call both, will generate two events.
webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url1));
webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url2));
```

However, I suspect that you're having some lifetime issues, given that you go out of scope with the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) (it's never properly disposed of).

Answer (score 0):

I...personally wouldn't use Rx here, probably. This sounds more suitable to the Task library, actually; here's something like what I'd probably do:

```
void Main()
{
    var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => GetUrl("http://www.google.com"))
        .ContinueWith(tsk => ParseCsv(CheckAndHandleError(tsk)))
        .ContinueWith(tsk => 
            { 
                if(CheckAndHandleError(tsk)) 
                    return GetUrl("http://www.yahoo.com"); 
                else
                    return string.Empty;
            })
        .ContinueWith(tsk => ParseCsv(CheckAndHandleError(tsk)));

}

private T CheckAndHandleError<T>(Task<T> task)
{
    if(task.IsFaulted)
    {
        // you'll need to handle the tsk.Exception here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    else
    {
        return task.Result;
    }   
}

private string GetUrl(string address)
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var stream = client.OpenRead(address);
        using(var rdr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return rdr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}

private bool ParseCsv(string csvText)
{
    // whatever this is
    Console.WriteLine(csvText);
    return true;
}
```